# To find the Index value of an two dimensional array in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

There are some numbers in an two-dimensional array, `@quality_list`.
I would like to extract the index number, `index_max`, of the maximum number.

```
my $max = max( @{$quality_list[0]} );
my $index_max = qw($max)
```

Comment: If it's a 2-dimensional array, then one index number cannot identify the max value. [ask], [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of optimsiation problem you likely want to use `max_by` from `List::UtilsBy`:

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( max_by );

my @values = @{ $quality_list[0] };
my $maximal_index = max_by { $values[$_] } 0 .. $#values;
```

This returns the value from the input list (the list `0 .. $#values`; i.e. a list of array indices) that gives the largest result of the `max_by` control block (i.e. has the largest value in the `@values` array).

Answer (score 0):

For the maximum of one row (as you appear to be doing):

```
my $row = $quality_list[0];
my $max = max(@$row);
my @max_indexes = grep { $row->[$_] == $max } 0..$#$row;
```

For the maximum of the entire 2d array (as you appear to have requested):

```
my $max = max map { @$_ } @quality_list;
my @max_indexes;
for my $y (0..$#quality_list) {
   my $row = $quality_list[$y];
   push @max_indexes,
      map { [ $y, $_ ] }
         grep { $row->[$_] == $max } 0..$#$row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your max value will show up only once (a less general case of ikegami's solution which uses List::Util) you can get the index and the max value in one pass, thus doing a lot less iteration:

```
my $idx = 0;
my @max = (-1, undef);
map { @max = $_ > $max[0] ? ($_, $idx++) : @max }
    map { @$_ } @quality_list;

print "max value $max[0] at index [" .
      int($max[1]/scalar(@{$quality_list[0]})) .  "," .
      $max[1] % scalar(@{$quality_list[0]}) . "]\n";
```

Edit: switched from pre to post increment to fix off-by-one.

Also, here is a version that avoids the array copying and works with all negative and positive values. Worth mentioning that your max can show up more than once in contrast to what I said above, though technically only the first instance of it will be reported.

```
my $idx = 0;
my @max = $quality_list[0][0];
map { @max = ($_, ++$idx) if $_ > $max[0] }
    map { @$_ } @quality_list;

print "max value $max[0] at index [" .
      int($max[1]/scalar(@{$quality_list[0]})) .  "," .
      $max[1] % scalar(@{$quality_list[0]}) . "]\n";
```